# Introspecting based on datasource defined in prisma/schema.prisma / Error: P4002

Tags: nuxt.js, prisma, supabase-database, supabase

starting new project and ran prisma db init, then i ran prisma db pull. Getting this error:
[image]

**Introspecting based on datasource defined in prisma/schema.prisma

Error: P4002

The schema of the introspected database was inconsistent: Illegal cross schema reference from public.profiles to auth.users in constraint profiles_id_fkey. Foreign keys between database schemas are not supported in Prisma. Please follow the GitHub ticket: prisma/prisma#1175**

Is there any explanation to it? I couldn't find a clear answer to this issue. Like, what would be the next step to do to avoid that error.

couldn't find a solution in this ticket: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1175

Comment: Does this workaround not work for you till the time this is natively supported by prisma? https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1175#issuecomment-1195274592

Comment: thnx. this workaround helped as well: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1175#issuecomment-1195274592